# Font DinPro-Light issue on Mac Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have used the font "DinPro-Light" on my website. It works fine on all browsers on PC except Mac's browsers. The other weights (Regular, Bold, etc) are fine on both PC and Mac. Only the "light" weight is causing the problem. It is rendered like the regular weight...

Below is the CSS used for the font. Thank you...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DinPro';
    src: url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Light.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Light.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DinPro';
    src: url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Regular.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/DinPro/PFDinTextPro-Regular.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This css line fixed the problem:
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;